# How can I reset background color on keypress?

Tags: html, function, onmouseover, onkeydown

I'm trying to have divs that, when moused over, change their background color, and being able to reset those colors. I've managed the former, but the latter is giving me issues.

As written, the divs do, in fact, change color, but attempting to press a key does not result in anything. I've also tried to put the resetColor function in the same block of Script, but doing so makes it so I can't even hover over and change the colors of those divs. As such, I'm wondering what I should do to be able to reset the divs' color?

```js
function randomColor(element) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
  console.log(bgColor);
  element.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}

function resetColor(element) {
  element.backgroundColor = '#ffff99';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.colorCell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorCell" onmouseover="randomColor(this.style)" onkeydown="resetColor(this.style)">
  <!--Successfullly changed color-->
  <!--<a onmouseover="colorCell.body.style.backgroundColor = '#f39352'">-->
</div>
<div class="colorCell" onmouseover="randomColor(this.style)" onkeydown="resetColor(this.style)">
</div>
<div class="colorCell" onmouseover="randomColor(this.style)" onkeydown="resetColor(this.style)">
</div>
```

Comment: Many points where you could start. Nowadays there are on rare cases where something like the `onmouseover`-attribtue is acceptable. You should always try to split the JS and HTML completely to be independent. Add an EventListener in your JS. Then you can ramoily roll a Hexnumber (also 8-bit color just as RGB) in one run. The issue itself will be solved if you use the `onclick`-attribute instead of `keydown`

Comment: You should switch to a single event listener rather that repeating the same code in your markup.

Comment: onkeydown use with input fields if you want to use it with div add  tabindex="0" in your div and then check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an idea can be to :

- add an event listener at document level
- stored hovered cell
- if one cell is over and keydown reset the celle style

```js
let elementHovered = null;

function getRandomColor() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function randomColor(element) {
  const bgColor = `rgb(${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()}, ${getRandomColor()})`;
  console.log(bgColor);
  element.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}

function resetColor(element) {
  element.backgroundColor = '#ffff99';
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('.colorCell')].forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    elementHovered = event.target.style;
    randomColor(elementHovered);
  });
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  if (elementHovered) {
    resetColor(elementHovered)
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.colorCell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ffff99;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorCell"></div>
<div class="colorCell"></div>
<div class="colorCell"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have to wonder real quick what the Header to these documents look like, as in how they call aspects of each other? And, for that matter, what filetype you used for the functions?

Comment: The functions are stored in a standard js file and don't need specific header. If you want to used my reply an idea can be to create a js file with script part and include this file in a script tag

Comment: @ZacharyBreen does it solve your issue ? if yes could you please mark the rely to close the topic

Comment: What I meant moreso is, I wrote this in notepad++, and as such I'm not sure what I'd do with the js file to make the main html file use it

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ycn4zx9b/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="colorCell" onmouseover="randomColor(this)"></div>
<div class="colorCell" onmouseover="randomColor(this)"></div>
<div class="colorCell" onmouseover="randomColor(this)"></div>
```

CSS is still the same as you provided.

JS:

```
function randomColor(element) {
 var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
 var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
 element.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
 element.classList.add(`reset-me`);
}

function resetColor(element) {
 element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffff99';
}

window.onload = () => {
 document.getElementsByTagName(`body`)[0].addEventListener(`keydown`, () => {
  var itemss = document.querySelectorAll(`.reset-me`);
  for (var i = 0; i < itemss.length; i++) {
   resetColor(itemss[i]);
  }
 });
}
```

Keypress won't work on such elements on which you cannot enter something.
Make the event global instead and it should work.